# PHP Como obtener el nombre de un archivo variable?

Tags: php, archivo, phpexcel

Estoy intentando importar un libro de excel en PHP pero el nombre de este archivo se cambia todos los dias.

```
$nombreArchivo="/Carpeta/archivovariable.xlsx"
```

¿Hay algun codigo para añadir en la ruta como "%%" o "*" para que se importe el archivo sin importar el nombre?

---

Agradezco su ayuda, encontre la solucion y aqui se las dejo.
Este codigo lee todos los archivos dentro de un directorio y obtiene su nombre y extension:

```
<?php
$directorio = opendir("."); //ruta actual
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
{
    if (is_dir($archivo))//verificamos si es o no un directorio
    {
         //Aqui hacen algo si no es un directorio
    }
    else
    {
        echo $archivo . "<br />"; //Aqui hacen lo que quieran con cada      archivo
    }
}
?>
```

Fuente: http://www.elcodigofuente.com/leer-archivos-directorio-carpeta-php-812/#comment-79954

Comment: ¿es el único archivo .xlsx en la carpeta o existen otros?

Comment: Hola iunifrenedor, existen otros

Comment: @Spirit si vas a agregar información debes realizarlo en tu misma pregunta mediante la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/134994/edit), saludos.

Comment: Si señor... gracias

Comment: glob devuelve un array independientemente si en la carpeta hay solo un archivo que cumple con el filtro, tenes que recorrer el array como está indicado en el código de ejemplo que agregué.

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar [opendir](http://php.net/manual/es/function.opendir.php) y [readdir](http://php.net/manual/es/function.readdir.php) o [scandir](http://php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php) o [glob](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php). Suponiendo que conoces el directorio base.

```
$directorio_base = __DIR__ ;

$dir_handle = opendir($directorio_base);

while(($archivo = readdir($dir_handle)) !== false) {
  $ruta = $directorio_base . '/' . $archivo;
  echo $ruta . PHP_EOL;
  if(is_file($ruta)) {
      $ext = pathinfo($ruta, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      if($ext === 'xlsx') {
          //hacer lo que se tiene que hacer con el archivo
      }
  }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
```

Con [glob](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php)

```
$directorio_base = __DIR__ ;

$archivos = glob($directorio_base . '/*.xlsx');

foreach($archivos as $archivo) {
    //trabajar con cada archivo
}
```