# extraer nombre (sin extension) de un archivo ubicado en una carpeta

Tags: php, imagen, variables

Como puedo extraer el nombre de, por ejemplo, un archivo de imagen ubicado en la carpeta imagenes?

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es crear la variable en `PhP`
de esta manera:

```
$img = "nombre del archivo";
```

Lo que quiero es que ese nombre de archivo sea dinámico, y cambie por cada **archivo**. En este caso le puse números como nombre a los archivos de imagen, es decir:

> 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc...

Y están en una carpeta del servidor.

Esto lo estoy intentado hacer para crear una galería de imágenes que se muestre automáticamente (para no crear 1 div y 1 modal por cada imagen que quiero subir a mi pagina) y que además al hacer click en un botón "ver más" me muestre el resto de las imágenes de la carpeta en mi galería.

Entonces si logro darle el nombre del archivo como valor de la variable $img, podría usar la variable para hacer echo del div de la galería y del modal.

creo que en `Javascript` se puede crear la variable de la forma:

```
var img = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

pero desconozco si en `PhP` se puede crear de la misma forma, es decir,

```
$img = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

No se si me expliqué bien, soy nuevo en esto... gracias por la paciencia.

Comment: en esa pregunta fíjate esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134998/81450 (cambia la extensión xlsx por jpg)